# Откуда в сокетах python берется значение 4096

Tags: python, сокет, ip, передача-данных

Возник такой вопрос в python в библиотеки socket рекомендованное значение для функции получения данных `recv` 4096 байт.

Я не очень понимаю, чем обоснованно данное значение и откуда оно вообще берется. В документации по этому сказано очень скупо:

> **Note:** For best match with hardware and network realities, the value of bufsize should be a relatively small power of 2, for example, 4096.

И казалось бы, следует копать в аппаратную сторону, но например `MTU` Ethernet-кадров составляет **1500** байт, ограничение для `TCP/UDP` чуть меньше `2^16`.

Comment: 4K это типичный размер страницы виртуальной памяти -- т.е. единицы памяти, которой манипулирует ОС

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение буфера — это объем информации, который сервер прочитал откуда-то, но ещё недоставленный до потребителя, плюс запас на время, пока программа запросит следующую порцию.

Например, если время реакции сервера 100мс, время обработки на клиенте 50мс, а данные поступают 1024 в секунду, то буфер нужен 512, чтоб эти данные поступали непрерывно при синхронном обмене (игры). При этом желательно, чтоб сообщение помещалось в буфер, чтобы за цикл это сообщение можно было обработать.

Если буфер ещё больше, то несколько сообщений обрабатываются за раз. Но слишком большой буфер не даст подстроиться под лаги интернета, и вы поймёте, что подключение упало и нужно переподключиться, когда будет уже заметно потребителю.

Comment: "буфер нужен 512", — почему? Принцип, вроде, понимаю, но в расчётах запутался

Comment: Меня тоже это немного смутило, куда девается еще 512

Comment: То ли я тупой и не понял ответа от слова совсем, то ли вы путаете буфер системного вызова recv с каким-то другим буфером. Системный вызов recv (на примере линукса) всегда незамедлительно возвращает данные, если в системном буфере полученных данных есть хотя бы один байт данных (и если не выставлен флаг MSG_WAITALL), поэтому никакие рассуждения про «лаги интернета» к нему в принципе неприменимы. Ну и ещё не очень понятно, про TCP или про UDP речь (вы почему-то ссылаетесь на игры, которые обычно используют UDP)

Comment: Ответ @avp в комментариях к вопросу, более подходящий, ваш же скорее объясняет принцип работы, но не откуда берется рекомендация в 4096.

Comment: 4096 - это 4*2 в 10. Так сказать, круглое число. Плюс 4к - это такой очень удобный для менеджера памяти размер (обычно, менеджеру памяти хорошо работается с блоками в 4 или 8кб).

Comment: 150+150 мс - 300 байт - округляем вверх.

Comment: @andreymal тренеруюсь в писательстве, пока не очень выходит, особенно перед сном. ну а написать правдоподобный, но неправильный ответ это лучший способ получить правильный)

Comment: @eri все равно не очень понимаю, как вы складывая милисекунды получаете байты

Comment: если данные генерируются со скоростью 1024 байт в секунду, то за 300 мс будут готовы 307 байт.

Comment: @andreymal я описал буфер для синхронной работы. следующий буфер передается когда клиент ответил ack на предыдущий.

Comment: @eri при попытке нагуглить о чём речь гугл ответил мне «TCP transmission is always asynchronous», так что я всё равно ничего не понимаю